# .call method throws error at this keyword

Tags: javascript, call

In the simplified code below I attempt to push the string goblin into the creatures array.  Unfortunately I get an error at `this.push(x)`.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at addName`

If `this` points to the object that owns it, shouldn't that be the creatures object when it is used with a `call` statement?  Thanks so much for any help!

```js
'use strict';
 
var creatures;
 
creatures = ['zombie', 'skeleton', 'orc', 'giant spider'];

function addName(x) {
  this.push(x)
}

addName('goblin').call(creatures);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call like `addName.call(creatures)`. Call the `call` function on the function itself, not on its result, which you have done. And if your function takes parameters, you can pass those parameters after passing the context.

```js
'use strict';
 
var creatures;
 
creatures = ['zombie', 'skeleton', 'orc', 'giant spider'];

function addName(x) {
  this.push(x)
}

addName.call(creatures, 'goblin');

console.log(creatures);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code

- **Invoking `call` method on `undefined`** - You are invoking `call` method to the return value of `addName` method call which returns `undefined` while call can be invoked only on `function`.
- `call` method takes `this` argument as the first parameter and *arguments to the function* to be invoked from the *second parameter onward*.

You need to pass *goblin* as the second parameter of `call`

```
 addName.call(creatures, 'goblin');
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes suites better in this situation I believe

```
    'use strict';

class Creatures5{
    constructor(){
        this.creatures = ['zombie', 'skeleton', 'orc', 'giant spider'];
    }   


    addName(x) {
      this.creatures.push(x)
        console.log(this.creatures)
    }
}
var CreatureObj = new Creatures5;
CreatureObj.addName('goblin');
```

OR you can

```
'use strict';
var creatures = ['zombie', 'skeleton', 'orc', 'giant spider'];

function addName(x){
    creatures.push(x)
}


this.addName.call('goblin')
```